# Quantiles of the Chi-square over degrees of freedom distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-distribution

I've been studying the EPA's procedures for calculating Method Detection Limits (MDLs) based on [40 CFR 136 (Appendix B)](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2012-title40-vol24/pdf/CFR-2012-title40-vol24-part136-appB.pdf).

After calculating the MDL, they give the constants for calculating a confidence interval for the MDL

> according
>   to the following equations derived
>   from percentiles of the chi square over degrees
>   of freedom distribution ($\chi^2$/df).
>
> LCL = 0.64 MDL
>
> UCL = 2.20 MDL

Based on an example at http://www.chemiasoft.com/chemd/node/58, I found that $\sqrt \frac{df}{\chi^2(\alpha/2, df)} $ and $\sqrt \frac{df}{\chi^2(1 -\alpha/2, df)} $ give the constants for the MDL limits.  I confirmed this using R with

```
# The EPA document anticipates a sample size of 7, or 6 df
sqrt(6 / qchisq(.975, 6)) # 0.6443934
sqrt(6 / qchisq(.025, 6)) # 2.202066
```

I'm afraid I don't understand the derivation, however.  It seems to be a chi-squared variable divided by it's degrees of freedom would be the same as a chi-square variable divided by a constant, which has a Gamma distribution.  So I'm fairly certain I'm missing something obvious and would appreciate any help in understanding the derivation of the confidence interval for the MDL.

Comment: It's a confidence interval for the standard deviation, written "$S$" in the regs.  Since $S^2$ is the variance and $S$ must be positive, the CI is obtained by taking the square roots of the CI for the variance.

Comment: @whuber Oh.  So if $MDL = T * S$, then $LCL = 0.64 * MDL = 0.64 * T * S$.  In other words, the confidence interval for the MDL is $T$ multiplied by the confidence limits for $S$?